# How can I copy a directory but ignore some files in Perl?

Tags: perl, copy

In my Perl code, I need to copy a directory from one location to another on the same host excluding some files/patterns (e.g. *.log, ./myDir/abc.cl). 
What would be the optimum way of doing this in Perl across all the platforms?
On Windows, xcopy is one such solution. On unix platforms, is there a way to do this in Perl?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227613/how-can-i-copy-a-directory-recursively-and-filter-filenames-in-perl

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for [rsync](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps). It's not Perl, but it's going to work a lot better than anything you make in Perl:

```
% rsync --exclude='*.log' --exclude='./myDir/abc.cl' SOURCE DEST
```

If you have a bunch of patterns, you can put those all in a file:

```
*.log
./myDir/abc.cl
```

Now ignore all the patterns in a file:

```
% rsync --exclude-from=do_not_sync.txt SOURCE DEST
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `File::Find`, and step over each file, but instead of calling `File::Copy`'s `copy()` on each file, first test to see if it matches the pattern, and then `next` if it does.

Answer (score 1):

On *nix, you can use native tar command, with [-exclude options](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/tar/exclude.html). Then after creating the tar file, you can bring it over to your destination to untar it.