# Linux commands (cp, rm) are not executed in a perl script. Some works. But no error are returned

Tags: linux, perl, command, cp

I'm having a very strange error.

I run a perl script which executes linux commands. They are executed like this:

```
my $err = `cp -r $HTML /tssobe/www/tstweb/$subpath/$HTMLDIR1`;
myLog("$err");
```

And $err is empty, which mean the command didn't return and error. (right?)

I tried to execute the linux command with exec "" or system (), but no success.
I tried to change the path. Same.

Also, I tried to run only the cp command in a new perl script. It works.
But not in my full perl script.

In this perl script, some commands are working, some are not.

The script was working yesterday, Not anymore this morning. No changes have been made in the meantime.

I tried a lot of things, I would be glad if anybody has an idea.

EDIT:
The server was having a lot of processes unterminated. Cleaning those solved the problem.
So the problem is related to another application, but I'll improve the logging thanks to your comments.

Comment: You lack error reporting. Add `use autodie qw(:all);` near the top of your script and it will abort with useful error messages when something goes wrong.

Comment: Be very careful with the input you use for the `$HTML` or `$subpath` or `$HTMLDIR1` variables -- if any of them allow through [shell metacharacters](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/78.html), you've written an insecure tool. Better would use [`File::Copy::Recursive`](http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/File-Copy-Recursive-0.38/Recursive.pm) or similar tools to avoid the use of the shell completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Small problem:** you are NOT capturing STDERR, so you won't see the error (you are also not checking `$?` return code).

You should do

```
my $err = `cp -r $HTML /tssobe/www/tstweb/$subpath/$HTMLDIR1 2>&1`;
```

to redirect STDERR to STDOUT, or use one of the modules for running commands.

---

**Large problem:**

You should not run system commands from Perl for which Perl-native modules exist. In this case: [`File::Copy::Recursive`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Copy::Recursive) module.

You can also [roll your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227613/how-can-i-copy-a-directory-recursively-and-filter-filenames-in-perl) directory copied from `File::Copy`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using backticks? Add -v to the cp commmand to see something in STDOUT and redirect the STDERR to STDOUT and check the cmd exitcode not the error message in the STDERR.

What about printing out the command output right after the execution?

```
my $err = `cp -rv $HTML /tssobe/www/tstweb/$subpath/$HTMLDIR1 2>&1`;
my $exitcode = $? >> 8;
warn "Output: $err\nexitcode: $exitcode\n";
```

It would be better to use qx. Check this: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=454715

Comment: Why do you think qx// would be better?

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to quote arguments that may potentially contain any shell special characters, including spaces.  As shell will do word splitting on the string given to it, if `$HTML` contains a space `cp` would get more arguments than you expect.  Perl has very simple mechanism for that: `\Q\E`.  Here is how you do it:

```
my $err = `cp -r \Q$HTML\E \Q/tssobe/www/tstweb/$subpath/$HTMLDIR1\E 2>&1`;
```

Anything except for alphanumeric will be backslash escaped before passing it to the shell.  And you would provide exactly 2 arguments to `cp` regardless of what is in those variables.