# Identifying the difference between ordinary folders and "."/".." folders

Tags: perl, file, directory

I'm writing a Perl script to automatically copy PDFs from a folder.

Users are unable to access folders they don't have permission for so they don't accidentally gain access to any information they aren't supposed to.

I have a rough mock-up which works except for one bug: it keeps seeing the `.` and `..` folders and opens them entering infinite loops.

The following conditional statement checked to see the file was a PDF, which would then pass to my `copyPDF`, which checks for exceptions and then copies the file; otherwise it passes and tries to open as a folder if a folder scans that content and repeats.

I've tried a number of ways to ignore the `.` and `..`  but it always leads to ignoring all other subfolders as well. Has anyone got a work around?

```
if ($file =~ /\.pdf$/i) {
  print "$file is a pdf\n";
  $fileLocation = "$directoryName/$file";
  copyPDF("$fileLocation", "$file");
}
elsif ($file == '.') {
  #print "argh\n";
}
else {
  $openFolder = "$directory/$file";
  print "*$openFolder";
  openNextDirectory("$openFolder");
}
```

Comment: Show us all the code for your file finding.  Are you using File::Find?  Show us all of that.

Comment: While we're at it, [don't quote `"$vars"`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#What%27s-wrong-with-always-quoting-%22$vars%22?) for no reason.

Comment: `next if $file =~ /^\.\.?$/` is a common way to solve this problem.

Comment: I'd suggest that `$file ne '..' && $file ne '.'` is more explicit and requires less thinking on the part of the reader.

Comment: ... and doesn't match files called `".\n"` or `"..\n"`.

Comment: Is this the body of the `copyPDF` subroutine? Please show your program in its entirety. The [`-d` and `-f` operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) would be useful here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!!!

```
$file == '.'
```

produces

```
Argument "." isn't numeric in numeric eq (==)
```

because you are asking Perl to compare two numbers. You should be using

```
$file eq '.'
```

See [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) for more information about perl's operators.

Answer (score 2):

This old question has some great answers that address this and similar questions:

[How can I copy a directory recursively and filter filenames in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227613/how-can-i-copy-a-directory-recursively-and-filter-filenames-in-perl)

Answer (score -3):

use the `File::Find` module

```
use File::Find;
use File::Copy;

my $directory = 'c:\my\pdf\directory';
find(\&pdfcopy, $directory);

sub pdfcopy() {
    my $newdirectory = 'c:\some\new\dir';
    return if ($File::Find::name !~ /\.pdf$/i);
    copy($File::Find::name, $newdirectory) or 
    die "File $File::Find::name cannot be copied: !";
}
```

Comment: Missing `use warnings; use strict;`, your code doesn't even parse, useless use of wrong prototype, your regex is wrong, you misspelled `$!`.

Comment: The regex is (mostly) correct but only since your second edit. You fixed the parse error and the regex but not the other 3 issues.