# how to create a script from a perl script which will use bash features to copy a directory structure

Tags: perl

hi i have written a perl script which copies all  the entire directory structure from source to destination  and then i had to create a restore script from the perl script which will undo what the perl script has done that is   create a script(shell) which can use bash features to restore the contents from destination back to source i m struggling to find the correct function or command which can copy recursively (not an requirement) but i want exactly the same structure as it was before

Below is the way i m trying to create a file called restore to do the restoration process
i m particularly looking for algorithm.

Also restore will restore the structure to a command line directory  input if it is supplied if not You can assume the default input supplied to perl script
$source
$target
in this case we would wanna copy from target to source

**So we have two different parts in one script.**

**1 which will copy from source to destination.**

**2 it will create a script file which will undo what part 1 has done 
i hope this makes it very clear**

```
 unless(open FILE, '>'."$source/$file") 
 {

    # Die with error message 
    # if we can't open it.
    die "\nUnable to create $file\n";
  }

    # Write some text to the file.

    print FILE "#!/bin/sh\n";
    print FILE "$1=$target;\n";
    print FILE "cp -r \n";

    # close the file.
     close FILE;

    # here we change the permissions of the file
      chmod 0755, "$source/$file";
```

The last problem i have is i couldn't get $1 in my restore file as it refers to a some variable in perl

but i need this for getting command line input when i run restore as $0 = ./restore $1=/home/xubuntu/User

Comment: [How to copy a directory recursively using perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227613/how-can-i-copy-a-directory-recursively-and-filter-filenames-in-perl)

Comment: @Prix the problem also involves how do include the copy module in shell

Comment: File::Copy has been a core module for a while.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera may be my way of asking the question is wrong

Answer (score 3):

First off, the standard way in Perl for doing this:

```
 unless(open FILE, '>'."$source/$file") {
    die "\nUnable to create $file\n";
 }
```

is to use the `or` statement:

```
open my $file_fh, ">", "$source/$file" 
    or die "Unable to create "$file"";
```

It's just easier to understand.

A more modern way would be `use autodie;` which will handle all IO problems when opening or writing to files.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $file_fh, '>', "$source/$file";
```

You should look at the Perl Modules [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html), [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html), and [File::Copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) for copying files and directories:

```
use File::Find;
use File::Basename;

my @file_list;
find ( sub {
          return unless -f;
          push @file_list, $File::Find::name;
     },
 $directory );
```

Now, `@file_list` will contain all the files in `$directory`.

```
for my $file ( @file_list ) {
    my $directory = dirname $file;
    mkdir $directory unless -d $directory;
    copy $file, ...;
}
```

Note that *autodie* will also terminate your program if the `mkdir` or `copy` commands fail.

I didn't fill in the `copy` command because where you want to copy and how may differ. Also you might prefer `use File::Copy qw(cp);` and then use `cp` instead of `copy` in your program. The `copy` command will create a file with default permissions while the `cp` command will copy the permissions.

You didn't explain why you wanted a bash shell command. I suspect you wanted to use it for the directory copy, but you can do that in Perl anyway. If you still need to create a shell script, the easiest way is via the :

```
print {$file_fh} << END_OF_SHELL_SCRIPT;
Your shell script goes here
and it can contain as many lines as you need.
Since there are no quotes around `END_OF_SHELL_SCRIPT`,
Perl variables will be interpolated
This is the last line. The END_OF_SHELL_SCRIPT marks the end
END_OF_SHELL_SCRIPT

close $file_fh;
```

See [Here-docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3c%3cEOF) in Perldoc.

Answer (score 1):

First, I see that you want to make a copy-script - because if you only need to copy files, you can use:

```
system("cp -r /sourcepath /targetpath");
```

Second, if you need to copy subfolders, you can use -r switch, can't you?