# Perl recursively copy files of specific format

Tags: perl, recursion, file-io

*Note: The related question is solved by use of a deprecated module and is not consistent across OS. The answer to current question uses newer modules and hence is being posted here.*

I have a module that in turn uses the [File::NCopy](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-NCopy/) CPAN module for recursively copying files from  to .

The problem is - I need to recursively copy only the files of specific file type to the destination. Is there any way to filter the source by extension?

As an alternative - is there a way to copy all files except the hidden files? My main problem being the .git folder also gets copied - which is not desired.

Platform: MacOS

Alternatives explored:

1) File::Copy::Recursive module :- seems to provide only recursive copy of files or directories. Does not seem to help with either hidden files or exclude filter

2) Using rsync -avz --exclude=".*" :- unable to combine this with recursive copy functionality.

3) Homegrown solution similar to [How can I copy a directory recursively and filter filenames in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227613/how-can-i-copy-a-directory-recursively-and-filter-filenames-in-perl) :- Might be the last resort - but does not seem portable unless tweaked and tested across different platforms. **Will be falling back to this unless a module already exists.**

4) https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class::Dir :- Seems plausible - will be running a quick implementation using this.

**Implemented Solution:**

I used the recursive module and the Path::Class::Dir

```
 dir($sourceDir)->recurse(callback => sub {
     my $file = shift;

     return if($file eq '.' || $file eq '..');

     return if -d $file;

     if (<custom filter>)
     {
         my $path = file($file)->relative($sourceDir);
         fcopy("$sourceDir/$path", "$destinationDir/$path") or die "Could not perform fcopy: $!";
     }
 });
```

Without the relative path - the destination folder structure does not seem to be the same as the source folder structure.

Comment: Minor note: [`File::NCopy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::NCopy) reports that it is deprecated and suggests using [`File::Copy::Recursive`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Copy::Recursive) instead.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: You might have to make a homegrown solution if you want to exclude dot files AFAIK.

Comment: That linked question shows how to use File::Copy (which the pointer from the depricated module in the OP wraps) to recursively copy files matching criteria.

Comment: for alternative, maybe you can use this: rsync -avz --exclude=".*" from to this will exclude all hiden files, but i dont know is this acceptable in your script ?

Comment: OS is mac... And I did look into File::Copy::Recursive - but it seems to copy either file or directory recursively - I can already perform that - I was looking for any existing module to filter the files.

Comment: @klerk - since I'm using it through a module - I need a way to combine the exclusion with the recursive copy command. I can fallback to a homegrown solution - but I figured it might be better to check if something exists before going that route

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class::Dir has traversal and recursion functions that can take a closure with code to run. This would be easy to use to perform a recursive copy for files matching certain criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution is to use [`File::Copy::Recursive`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aCopy%3a%3aRecursive) to copy the directory structure fully, and then to go back with [`File::Find::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule) to determine all the dirs that you want to filter and then remove them.

Given that `.git` folders don't necessarily hold that much data, I think the performance hit from copying more files than you need to is likely to be pretty small.  The following would be sufficient to accomplish what you desire:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy::Recursive qw(dircopy pathrmdir);
use File::Find::Rule;

my $src = '...src...';
my $dest = '...dest...';

dircopy($src, $dest) or die "Can't dircopy: $!";

my @git = File::Find::Rule->directory()
                          ->name('.git')
                          ->in($dest);

pathrmdir($_) or die "Can't remove $_: $!" for (@git);
```

Alternatively, if you'd like to roll your own, you might take a look at [`File::Find::Rule #Further Examples`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule#Further-examples) which includes an example on how to "ignore CVS directories".